# Green's equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the boundary value problem (BVP)

$$u'' =-f, u(O) = u''(1) = 0 \,\,\text{on}\,\, [0,1],$$

Assume $f(x)$ is a real-valued continuous function on $[0,1]$. Then,
which of the following are correct?

1. The Green's function $G(x,s)= {x, 0 \le x \le s}$
   $G(x,s)={s, s\le x \le 1}$
2. Both $G$ and $\frac{\partial G}{\partial s}$ are continuous on $[0,1]$
3. $G(x, s)$ satisfies the homogeneous equation $u'' = 0$ for $ s \le x <s$  and $s < x \le 1$
4. The solution of the given BVP is $u(x)= \displaystyle \int_{0}^{x}sf(s)ds +\int_{0}^{x}xf(s)ds$

Second option is incorrect because green's function always possess discontinuity of first order at x=s,, and third is always true since it satisfies S.L.B.V.P but I'm stuck on first nd last option. If first is correct then fourth is obviously true but I have no idea about first option. Please help me.

[image: The problem]

Comment: It really helps readability to format questions using MathJax (see FAQ). Regards

Comment: I'm guessing there is a typo on $u''(1) = 0$, and it should read $u'(1) = 0$. If not, the problem is not well stated.